How do you "stealth" a relativistic superweapon?
There are questions about stealth in space and I have reviewed them; to me this is a much more niche case with different parameters that I think make this merit a different question.
What I want to have happen/already have happening
Occasionally during its expansion, the Galactic Empire (unrelated to the one with soldiers who can't aim) encounters a civilization or celestial body/set of celestial bodies that its ruling body deems too dangerous to interstellar society as a whole to allow to continue to exist. It might be a civilization that is so obsessed with violence at a national level that, if their technology were to develop further, they would pose a legitimate threat to the Empire and would start a war that costs billions of lives; it could be a civilization that's been taken over by a single government (AI or otherwise) that focuses all resources on expansion and domination of everything, and if they discover extraterrestrial life, they would immediately set out on a crusade to destroy all other species; it could also just be a rogue planet heading for an Imperial system that they want to take care of before it causes problems.
The Empire then calls on its most powerful weapon, which they've ominously termed the Devourer. Not necessarily its usage by the Empire, but its functions are the subject here. The Devourer is a large spacecraft (weighing several thousand metric tons and in a roughly cylindrical shape ~200 m in diameter and ~2.5 km in length), and it uses a Bussard-like fusion engine to accelerate at the rate of a missile (hundreds/thousands of $g$s with their advanced tech) up to very nearly lightspeed. At the front is a small magnetic intake, throughout the center are fuel tanks, and at the end is a fusion torchdrive. Covering the outside are various "scales", giant slabs of metal weighing tons each that have independent maneuvering and targeting mechanisms. When the onboard supercomputer detects through sensor arrays that the Devourer is nearing its target, it releases the scales and sends them onto impact trajectories towards their targets, and each scale strikes with unimaginable force (relativistic kinetic energy I approximate at around $10^{24}\,\text{J}$ given the approximate velocity). In most cases the scale passes straight through the planet after depositing enough energy in its surface to completely annihilate it.
In use, the Devourer is launched and, after a couple days' acceleration up to nearly lightspeed on an unobtainium engine and being cloaked with a stealth system when necessary, the Devourer releases cloaking when very near its target and deploys the scales; moving so close to $c$, targets only see the scales moments before they strike, and when they do, it's complete planetary annihilation.
The problem I see
In the case of rogue planetoids needing destruction, a Devourer can be sent on a lower-speed flyby and just drop a few scales on the target without stealth gear, and once the gravitational binding energy is overcome by the deployed scales, the Devourer can just turn around and be reused later.
However in this world the Devourer is (infrequently) used for annihilation of species. (Sure it might be considered immoral, but the Empire isn't perfectly moral either.) In all cases, the target species is one with highly-advanced technology; the Empire sort of overlooks species who aren't technologically-advanced enough to be considered "mature" and potentially a threat. So any target would necessarily have to be able to detect the launch of a Devourer. Although the Devourer's top speed is nearly lightspeed, it takes many days to reach that speed, and since safety protocols prevent the Devourer from being launched outside a certain distance, the target species is virtually guaranteed to be able to detect the launch and acceleration stages of the Devourer ahead of time, since the fusion drive is powerful and efficient but also projects a lot of radiation in all directions; for a civilization to be a target, they'd also incidentally have to be advanced enough to be able to detect the approach of a Devourer ahead of time and evacuate the planet/launch a projectile in its path to destroy it, which defeats the purpose.
Question
So, is there a mechanism by which one could effectively keep a huge heavily-blueshifted radiation source quiet while it approaches its target?
The fusion engine emits as waste heat roughly 1 TW of neutron and X-ray/gamma radiation in all directions as byproduct (the Devourer itself is kept cool by unobtainium radiators), and due to the velocity of the Devourer (ranging roughly from $c-1000$ meters per second to $c-1$ meters per second) this radiation is heavily blueshifted which will make it more obviously-visible. Additionally the telescopy technology of the target civilization is powerful enough to resolve signals in virtually all directions on any frequency, so that radiation being emitted is definitely going to be detectable if somehow unshielded.
What I'm looking for in an answer: What I want is a more-or-less feasible mechanism by which the Devourer can effectively redirect/absorb/otherwise make undetectable the signal it's emitting, which is way more than strong enough to be a good warning to civilizations on the receiving end of it. The tech level of the Empire is fairly high, so I will say that speculative technologies for energy redirection/absorption are allowed, but if I were willing to handwave a perfect Radiation-B-Gone-9000, I wouldn't be asking on WB:SE.
More context: there is FTL communication in the form of a certain type of communicator, but the Empire keeps the technology close to their belt. There's a mechanism by which two communicators can instantaneously transfer a small amount of information (around 1 kb/s) across arbitrary distance. This way, "real-time" data can be collected on a potential target's tech level and the decision to launch a Devourer can be made immediately rather than far too late for it to be of any use (see Mon's comment). There is also a small amount of FTL travel, effectively limited to emergency Imperial orders when a ship needs to be elsewhere now and the use of a dangerous but effective FTL drive is permitted.

One slight problem for your empire and it's high C weapon. Unless you have some form of FTL communication and/or travel capability is the sheer scale of the Galaxy. Say for example a dangerous species that has developed nuclear weapons is detected 500 lights years from the Empires Command Center  (which is really quite close in galactic terms.) By the time the signal arrives saying 'hey these guys have the bomb!' 500 years will have passed and they will probably have progressed to the point where they are capable of interstellar travel themselves. So the genie is already out of the bottle!

I agree with @Mon. As I read your question, I kept asking myself, "the speed of information is limited to the speed of light... just how far away must this thing be from its target to have a chance of being detected at all?" Although if you seriously want a "feasible mechanism" you probably should explain how you're getting around the relativistic mass problem.

Does it matter? Even in a crazy sci-fi setting, planetary evacuation of any reasonably sized population is not feasible. Sure, if they have a couple hours or even days of forewarning, politicians or the wealthy may be able to leave planet, but the majority of inhabitants will not. If planetary evacuation is feasible (everyone has their own spaceship) then there are already likely enough people off-planet at any given time to make even surprise destruction leave a significant fraction of the population as survivors.

BTW, even given an average density of 1 (eg, same as water), a cylinder with diameter 200m and lenth 2.5 km would have a mass of around 1.5 million tons.  If it's supposed to be supermassive machinery rather than lots of atmosphere-filled sections for crew I'd expect the density to be 2-4 at least, so if you are basing the dimensions on a target mass then make it smaller, if you are firm on the physical dimensions then it should be much, much more massive.

@Dragongeek Yes it does matter! And that's because it's not about staging an evacuation (which is clearly impossible in the scenario described). The 'problem' is that by the time the weapon arrives the 'dangerous species' has most likely already colonized other star systems and will have a fleet of high C starships of it's own. Those colonies WILL notice when the home system goes 'boom' and investigate. The most likely scenario? The Empire will only achieve what it wanted to avoid in the first place i.e. a war with the species it attacked.

Nothing, not even unobtanium, is going to pass through a planet. A shard with 10^24J is just as likely to be stopped as one with 10J.  The problem is sheer mass of the planet in front of the shard. It has nowhere to go and will turn into a plasma, just as the shard itself will.

@Dragongeek "Even in a crazy sci-fi setting, planetary evacuation of any reasonably sized population is not feasible." - at civilizations with Devourer power levels, disassembling planets for raw materials is a reasonable energy budget: in comparison, evacuating planets is childs play.

Sorry I noticed only now what @Mon said - yes, there is FTL communication in the form of a certain type of communicator, but the Empire keeps the technology close to their belt. There's a mechanism by which two communicators can instantaneously transfer a small amount of information (around 1 kb/s) across arbitrary distance. I have added this context to the question.

No warning, no need for stealth
This started being written with the intention of it being a comment on a couple of points in Antares' answer and grew out of control.
The question specifieds that the Devourer is travelling at between 1 and 1000 m/s less than the speed of light.  Assume the lesser speed, which is still 99.9997 c and that the Devourer takes 30 days to get up to speed. Let's also assume that the Devourer starts from 100 light years away, to give the target species the best chance possible.

The first light emissions from the Devourer's acceleration commencing take 100 years to arrive.
The Devourer takes 100 years and 30.1 days to arrive.  (Actually it's a bit less than that since the Devourer is chasing its initial radiation emissions from the start, but let's be generous.)
The target system has 30.1 days from first warning to impact.  (OK, the 100 light years launch made very little difference - at 20 light years the target would have 30.02 days of warning rather than 30.1 days.)
All of the light/radiation received in the first 3 days of that warning only show where the Devourer was 100 years ago.  The light showing where it was an hour before the scales will impact will arrive much less than a second before the Devourer does.
Except that the Devourer will not arrive - it will jettison "scales" at some point on a ballistic arc while the main craft itself does a flyby.  Without knowing at what point the scales will be jettisoned, knowing the Devourer's trajectory does not allow the scales to be targeted.  (If there is some concern that the scales could be intercepted and diverted by some extraordinarily powerful point-defence, then the scales should be made of radiation absorbent material and cooled to space-ambient temperature before separation.)

In summary, by travelling so close to lightspeed the total warning time the target system has is approximately equal to the initial acceleration time.  This is nowhere near enough time to evacuate a significantly populated planet and the only bits that need stealth are the MIRV "scales".  As long as the scales separate before the first light reaches the target's detectors - eg 30 days before impact - there is effectively zero chance of a successful interception.

This is the answer. At relativistic speeds being able to detect it won't give enough time to do more then evacuate a small amount of the population. Really what your empire needs to be wary of is information leaks - assuming you have some sort of FTL communication if the target civilization can access it and find out that it's been launched far enough in advance then maybe they could enact a full scale evacuation or some sort of tactical response.

Yes! Thank you for working that out :)

The only thing missing is now what the target system will "see=detect" during the flight near c (item #4). Is it a bright gamma ray signal (like a flash due to the blueshifting/moving of the emitting ship) or is it no signal or a frozen signal from 100years ago/when the acceleration phase ended.

@Antares It will be an increasingly blueshifted signal for the acceleration phase (eg 30 days), then nothing for most of the next hour or so (a 200m diameter body is too small to resolve at lightyear distances) then an extremely blueshifted and very rapidly expanding image of whatever radiation is reflected/emitted for the final few seconds/minutes (depending on instrument sensitivity).  Impacts of particles against the front shield would be the main source of "illumination" in interstellar space, I'd guess.

Disclaimer: Since the question is not "science-based", the Bussard ramjet is expected to not be limited by ~0.12c as in real life.
Use a reflector ahead
In fact, stealthing even a TW-range emission is pretty easy. Just have a inverse-cone shaped reflector ahead of your Devourer, that can double up as a passive targetting antenna, and also as a base for Bussard ramjet's magnetic particle trapper. While the Devourer accelerates, the side of that reflector directed towards its engine will effectively project a shadow with a small solid angle, even a single square degree would be enough to shadow the target planetary system ("a set of celestial bodies") from direct exposure by the engine.
You say that emission is in gamma-ray frequency level - this complicates matters to a degree, but with unobtainium present, you are allowed to invent a material that would reflect gamma rays. With existing materials you essentially disperse the gamma emission, not reflect it, but a reactor that can cool effectively 1e20J into a 1e12J blackbody radiation does display the outstanding capabilities of materials that exist in that Devouring Empire. So why not? Sometimes the simple solutions are exactly the best.
Use an intermediate or background star as floodlight
With your empire spanning several star systems, you are allowed to select the incoming vector of your attack. With this level of technology you are not limited by delta-V, so you can select a star system to position your Devourer in, then start its acceleration from the point in far regions opposite to the target, performing a very close star flyby at the highest speed possible by that time, and accelerate towards the target system further while having that star right behind the Devourer from the target's POV. This way the mere 1TW emission would be masked by way stronger (1e20+ W) emission by the star.
If there is no suitable star system between your empire and its target, find a background star with extreme mass (a G5 or so star would do for the former methos, but a red giant or a star of A9 or higher luminosity class would be required, sorted by inverse square range to the target), then position your Devourer on the line between the target and that star, from the target's POV, and rev up. This way the engine emission will be also hidden in the starlight of a star behind the Devourer, but the calculations would have to account the distances, the acceleration time profile and the exact expected view from the target at the "same time" with acceleration, thus the Devourer's actual trajectory would be pretty complex. Not an easy task I say, and the error margin is very small, but hey, you want stealth, you go long way to achieve it.
Screw the stealth altogether
If the actual detection capability of the target civilization happened to be on par with your Empire's tech, you might just forego stealthing, and depend on space maneuvering to avoid anything thrown at the Devourer by them. Okay they've seen it coming, at 0.99c or whatever, they've got a year or so to react - okay, we dodge their defensive fire with our 1e4G-capable engine, or just shred em with kinetic shrapnel each packing 1e24J released in dead space at indeterminate moments of time, about a local day before T0. Good luck for them hitting an unknown amount of two-meter-wide relativistic blocks of metal that don't radiate heat themselves from a light day away (you did account for interstellar dust collisions with this weapon, did you?), and missing a single one spells death for the planet that got hit.

Frame Challenge #1: This thing can not blow up a planet

Each scale strikes with unimaginable force (relativistic kinetic energy I approximate at around 10^24J
given the approximate velocity). In most cases the scale passes straight through the planet after depositing enough energy in its surface to completely annihilate it.

No it will not.  The entire mass of the scale will explode on the surface of the planet like a 239 teraton nuke.  This is about 2/3 the power of the asteroid that wiped out the dinosaurs: spoiler alert, it did not destroy the planet.  Each scale represents a major die-off of surface life, but they will not survive the penetration of the planet because of their own limited material properties, and they will certainly not blow a planet up. The binding energy of the Earth is so high that it would take the combined force of 200,000,000 scales to blow up an Earth sized planet.  Only the smallest of dwarf planets would be at risk of planetary disintegration from such a "small" impact.
Frame Challenge #2: This thing can not reach that fraction of the speed of light
Buzzard engines take a long time to accelerate and have a maximum theoretical speed due to the low density of available materials in space and the resistance caused by collecting such materials.  Newer calculations based on Voyager's measurements of the interstellar medium estimate such an engine being unable to exceed an acceleration of 0.04 kps per YEAR.  So, your only viable option to reach relativistic speeds with a fusion torch engine in most cases is to carry your fuel with you which means you can only convert about 0.645% of your ship's total mass to energy.  So if your ship is 50% fuel, 50% RKKV mass, then your max speed is only 0.08c not 0.999996c.  The only way such an engine would be advantageous is if you are operating it in a nebula, but even then they tend to max out at about twice the speed of a stored fuel torch engine due to drag.  Either way, your ship is neither able to move close to the speed of light using the technology you've described nor will it impact with nearly the energy you've calculated.  In fact, because it derives all of its energy from nuclear power, and a lot of that power is wasted through the mechanical inefficiencies of traversing space, this weapon will always be calculated to be less powerful than a traditional thermonuclear bomb of equivalent mass.
Also, if we use the KE of your impacts to assume that each scale weights in at about 23,000 tons. Slow this down 0.08c and we get an actual impact energy of 6.6e21J or 1.5 teratons.
Don't get me wrong, any weapon that can carpet-bomb a planet's surface with terraton level explosions is going to represent a significant extinction level event; so, it's still a viable doomsday weapon, but not nearly at the level of planetary annihilation that you are picturing.
Frame Challenge #3: No special actions are needed to avoid detection
Even at 0.08c, this thing is going to be VERY hard to see coming.  The whole "no stealth in space" concept relies heavily on 2 key assumptions: one is that things only move as quickly as modern spaceships (no more than a few km/sec) and two that they are using some manner of highly radiant engine within a couple of AU of the sensors meant to detect them.  The way you detect spaceship in space is by comparing the background heat to the object, but if this missile can accelerate at hundreds/thousands of g
s, then it will reach its max velocity with the first day of its several decade long journey between the stars. While it is in close proximity to a star, this massive surge of energy will be indistinguishable from the star directly behind it.  At most, it will look like a random solar flare in a neighboring star system... which is far from a news worthy observation. After this initial surge of energy, it has years to cool down before it gets close enough to the target to be detected. With the exception of a few small electrical components that need to be kept warm(ish), the whole thing will be almost as cold as space itself and no longer putting out 1 TW of neutron and X-ray/gamma radiation by the time it approaches any sort of plausible sensor range.
Furthermore, fast things cause radar smear which further reduces your ability to detect it.  Let's say for example your civilization puts out a grid of early detection stations in the outer solar system.  The missile is not coming straight at them; so, by the time it gets close enough for detection it is moving very quickly at a tangential angle to the scanners.  Even at 0.08c, this thing is moving at nearly 10,000 times its length and 125,000 times its width every second.  This means that if you have a scanner spending 1 second per frame scanning the area of sky that this thing is traversing, it's entire heat signature could be spread out across many pixels reducing the ability for any one pixel to distinguish it from its minimum threshold of sensitivity.  So even if it is reflective enough to detect when stationary, it's much much harder to detect simply because it is moving.  This means that the only scanners that might see it coming will be those directly in its path (on the target planet itself), and again, this this is cold by now; so, chances are they will not be able to detect it at a range of more than a few thousand km... which for a RKKV is not nearly enough time to react to it.
How to Overcome these Complications
There is no way to make an RKKV that fits all of these properties using your exact explanations of how things work. The power inherent in a fusion drive, even with a buzzard ramjet is insufficient to get that close to the speed of light.  Even using antimatter as a fuel source is unlikely to get you close to your desired speed and acceleration; so, in addition to hand waving thermodynamics and structural integrity with unobtanium, you will also need to handwave a powersource.  The problem with most sci-fi drives that can explain near light-speed travel is that they typically involve manipulating the inertia of your ship so that you can move faster with less energy.  But this does not actually help with a RKKV, because inertia dampening specifically limits the kinetic energy of your system. So, if you drop your effective mass to increase your speed, you still only hit with the energy of a reduced mass, high speed object such that you don't do any more damage than if you were moving slower without inertia dampening.  So to hit with more kinetic energy, you need to have more kinetic energy, and for that your ship needs a power source that goes WAY beyond the limits of classical physics.  So instead of fusion, you may need some manner of Zero-Point Quantum power generator of something of a totally handwavium nature.
As for the impact itself, no naturally occurring material could achieve a punch through and destruction of the plant, no matter how fast it is going, but there is one solution that could make it work.  Instead of artificially decreasing your ship's inertia, you increase it.  IF you increase your ship's inertia a few hundred million fold, then it will take a few hundred million times as much energy to accelerate, but your materials will also be proportionally more stable against impact and contain a proportionally increased kinetic energy such that when a 23,000 ton scale moving at just under the speed of light hits a planet, it actually contains the kinetic energy of a several gigaton scale moving at that speed, and more importantly, if it have so much more structural integrity from its increased inertia that the scale can pass through a planet without itself being destroyed or deflected by the constant shockwave of matter annihilation that it causes on impact. The outcome of this would be the equivalent of a matter/anti-matter reaction made up of all of the mass that makes up the planet along the scale's trajectory which should be plenty enough to annihilate an entire planet.
Unfortunately, nearly infinite power requirements also means your weapon has a nearly infinite power output.  As many orders of magnitude you increase your inertia, is by how much you need to increase the engine's power output to get it going; so, instead of looking like a minor solar flare, this thing might look the a star going nova when it launches... which also means it can only be launched from deep space because of how energetic the launch is.  But even with this in mind, the ship will still have lots of time to cool down by the time it gets close enough to detect, and radar smear only gets worse as you get faster; so, it will be really hard to detect as it approaches simply by its nature.

Note that the question does NOT have science-based tag, therefore while your frame challenges would be valid for real world, they are not necessarily valid for his world.

@Vesper Note that he also did not add any tags that expressly deny that this is science-based.  If he gives exact energy and velocity values without any indication of using magic to arrive at those values, treating it as a science-based question becomes the only appropriate way to answer it.

Also, he did use the kinetic weapons tag which means any science that pertains to the weaponization of kinetic energy applies; so, even if his setting is not 100% scientific, the tag specifically applies to the 'technology' of kinetic weapons.

There's the word "unobtainium" in the description of this device's engine, it counts as a strict denial for science-based.

@Vesper "the Devourer itself is kept cool by unobtainium radiators" <- The OP is hand waving the thermodynamic and perhaps structural integrity limitations of the engines, yes, but his descriptions of what it uses as a power source (Fusion powered Buzzard Engines) and what it's damage mechanic is (which he defines as kinetic) are explicitly science-based considerations.

Hey, Bussard ramjet is limited to some small fraction of c (I wrote 0.12) in science-based, no matter the power source, due to interstellar resistance vs the amount of propellant. And OP says "1000 m/s less than c" - no way it's science-based.

@Vesper Agreed. So either it's not actually a fusion powered bussard ramjet or it is limited to 0.12c.   Either way, the question has a few framing issue: thus the frame challenges.  That said, just because the question has framing issues does not make it unfixable or unanswerable. So I've updated my answer to include both how to answer it if you follow the specifications of the technologies listed and how to answer the question when you change the technologies to match the explained outcomes.

Cut the drive on final approach
One simple answer would be for the weapon to accelerate to its optimum kill speed, and then cut its drive, using thrusters or a gravity well to slingshot it to its ultimate destination.
With no atmospheric drag it could travel at that speed forever.
That way you would have a completely cold, completely inert object with no energy emissions. It would just need to have some kind of sensor absorbing stealth coating to prevent active sensors form picking it up at long rang.
For example, a ship could approach a solar system from behind some large obstacle such as a gas giant, or even the system's own sun, fire it's missile, and then have it cut the drive and loop around the gas giant\sun and simply coast in to it's target with enough kinetic energy to obliterate it.
Something similar, but at a lower velocity was used in The Expanse series of novels to drop kill shot asteroids on to Earth.

Interesting thought on just cruising in without active propulsion!

A threat is to be handled before being a threat...
You said it yourself, this Empire is kind of a god-like institution who decide what species are allowed to live and which are not, depending on their development and technological advancements. Implying they have the ultimate power of surveillance, knowing each and every living species and are observing and evaluating them (constantly).
At some point they have to decide wether or not the Devourer has to be used against them. You mentioned that those who are targeted can spot the Devourer. Granted, that might be a bit of a bummer. But can they do anything against it?
It would be implausible, because that would imply the Empire was not able to launch the Devourer in time or giving a species so much time for technological advancements to pose a significant threat to them. Being a gigantic surveillance institution with the sole purpose of ensuring their galactic superiority and having something like a credo of "prevail through first strike" this does not make sense.
Except, if your plot has the topic of the demise of that Empire of course.
It also sounds like the Empire has kind of unlimited resources. Meaning, they could potentially build several of those Devourers, position them at a Lagrange point behind the sun or a moon (or a planet) and be ready to fire as soon as they see fit. No need to travel there and loose time. Kind of an aircraft carrier you position to be in place when needed. Or even a small moon which is supposed to show the unquestionable superiority of the Empire over the "minor" species. Kind of an "ante": The species is allowed to "dwell" as long as they do not do something silly. The Devourer/Moon is there to ensure that the consequences will be severe and not a hollow threat.
Also... speed of light. It is a finite speed. Any observations are delayed. Therefore it is your friend in this case.
Travelling at the speed of light makes detection impossible already.
Scenario
As I understand your setting, you considered one Devourer being stationed somewhere. The "Species X" which is going to be regarded as a threat, can observe the Devourer being at some other place, potentially far away. Let's say, 20 to 100 lightyears. The problem you see is, that Species X can see, if the Devourer is being repositioned towards them, mainly because the Devourer is able to reach c but has a finite acceleration (of 100-1000 g). Also the Devourer is actively emitting gamma radiation during its flight.
Consequences for Species X:
(A) They will notice the start of repositioning because of an energy increase/blueshifting of the Devourer's signal. Given that they are able to have technology to detect gamma radiation and know how to identify the Devourer (which might be impossible already; space is vast and full of background radiation).
(B) In this case Species X would have something between 20 and 100 years at best to prepare counter-measures against the Devourer. If they were able cover up their efforts they might have been able to buy (much) more time prior to the start of the Devourer.
But they cannot "see" the Devourer accelerating, because this light still needs those 20 or 100 years to reach the homeplanet of Species X (See answer by KerrAvon2055 who clarifies this point)
(C) As soon as the Devourer reaches c, they cannot detect anything anymore. The Devourer emits or reflects radiation at the speed of light, which we know does not add up. The Devourer cannot be observed during its flight (or only with high amounts of uncertainty of the "real" distance, because it travels "right behind its emitted light" with almost no delay). It appears as if standing still. Only if it drops far below c the position and signals it will emit with the speed of c again will give away its position.
That means for the Empire:
(A) Reposition the Devourer often (every 10-20 years or so) by travelling at/close to c. This way every observing species will only be able to see the Devourer at (or close to) the old position and is not able to tell where the Devourer "really" is.
(B) Do not start the Devourer directly towards the intended target. The pre-warning time for Species X depends on the assumption that the Devourer is coming for them because it is on a straight course towards them. Imagine the Devourer is known (by word or observation) to change course often. Then Species X cannot tell if they are next or not.
(C) Any kind of specialized "cloaking hardware" is not necessary if you can reach c. Travelling at c makes you invisible effectively. Only phases of acceleration or deceleration are different. Even if you reach only 0.9c top speed, this means you are just 10% behind your last emitted light: If Species X spots you, you are already there.
(D) Build more Devourers, one for each potential Species X, because travel times of 20 or 100 years or more might be way to much time to react preemptively.

Being near c does not make you invisible.  In fact, macroscopic objects moving near c are going to glow insanely bright just due to ISM interaction.  If they are headed directly at you, they do not appear stationary - they appear to move much faster than c.  If they are moving in other directions, they also do not appear still.

@yaak, If it's moving right at you, you can't tell how fast it is going.  You might see a point of energy, but you can't tell if it is a small stationary object 2 light minutes away or an enormously fast and bright object 1ly away.

@Yakk: My text does not clearly distinguish visible light and the emitted gamma radiation, hence "seeing" and "detecting" are two different things actually. But I don't mean that the Devourer is "really invisible to everyone", it is just effectively invisible = undetectable to the targeted Species X home planet. Other observers might be able to detect different signals, that is true. Being stationary refers to the Devourer at c emitting light/radiation that also travels with c and both arrive at the observer at the same time. This means a long period without changing signal, aka "stationary"

@Antares no, it appears to move extremely fast when approaching, not "stationary".  The initial boost phase (with most of the light show) also doesn't appear stationary.  What a high speed does is make the approach phase take very little time from the perspective of the target: however, given the g forces described, the initial boost phase takes at least a month, and should be bright enough to be seen from a pretty extreme range.  At ~99.9% c and 100 ly range, you'd get 1 month boost and 1 month rapid approach, both of them extremely bright

@Yakk: Ok, I think I see what you mean! I have to think things over and probably update my text. Thank you for reporting back and insisting!

Blinding lights
Instead of stealth you can go the other route. Pump out so many signals they do not know what is coming. This can be done in two ways.
You say it is launched from a certain distance. The launching pad can have emitters that put out more and stronger wavelengths than the rocket. Like looking at a candle flame with a floodlight directly behind it,you'll only see the floodlight. It'll both obfuscate what they are doing, as well as any trajectory of the rocket should they know what is happening. Conceivably this could also be added to the rocket itself.
The second is multiple signals or swarms. Many signals become more difficult to track and act upon. They can obfuscate each other by signals interfering with each other. In combination with option one they can literally not know what hit them.
The swarm can also be used to make it unfeasible all are shot down. It is a tactic to overwhelm detection and countermeasures. You can launch multiple missiles, or if the single rocket is close to getting shot down it'll break into many tiny rockets that keep propelling their payload.

Make terminal approach using FTL, or have the Devourer go FTL to outrun its acceleration wavefront at some point.
FTL is virtually a requirement of this setting...you've got a galactic empire, you can't wait tens of thousands of years for information to cross it. Nor can you afford to wait millennia for the empire to detect such a civilization, investigate and find it to be in need of destruction, arrange for delivery or construction of a Devourer, and finally launch it at its target.


The fusion engine emits as waste heat roughly 1 TW of neutron and X-ray/gamma radiation in all directions as byproduct, and due to the velocity of the Devourer this radiation is heavily blueshifted

I think you making a storm in a glass of water.
Photons do not come with an ID card stating "Ms. Photon was emitted at 200 nm wavelength" which can be checked against the measured wavelength at the time of detection. We can determine blue or red shift only if we have a reference, which is either a set of known atomic emission lines or some other known emission profile.
For a generic and broad emission spectrum you have no way to determine if it is shifted unless you have a reference! And I assume your weapons are good enough to not leave any survivors around to tell the story of what hit them. They might just see a flash of X or gamma ray in the sky.
That said, if your civilization can build such a thing, can also afford building some energy recovery system to take back all those wasted X and gamma ray emission and convert it into reusable energy and waste heat in the far IR.
Planet buster 2.0, now environmental friendly!

You have a scale problem
The devourerer has an engine that is capable of speeding itself up to such a speed that it can fire passive "scales" at planetary-energy-binding levels of destruction.
This means that its engine is producing multiples of planetary-energy-binding levels of energy during the launch phase, on a very short term.
1000 Gs on a 100 kt ship is 1 MN of thrust.  E = FD, D = 1/2 at^2, so E = 1 MN * 1/2 * 10000 m/s^2 * t^2 - over 30 days, that is 3*10^22 J, or 1 * 10^16 watts.  The power output of a K1 scale civilization ("planetary scale").
But the devourer has to be more impressive than this.
The gravitational binding energy of Earth is 10^32 J, and we need the scales of the devourer (a fraction of its mass) be capable of disassembling planets.  At "planetary scale" power levels this would require 10000 billion years to accelerate the devourerer to "planetary binding energy" levels of speed.
So we need more power.  Our goal is 10^32 J, and say we want an accelleration time frame of 1 year.  10^32 J / 1 year is is 3 times 10^24 Watts - a K2 civilization level weapon, on "solar system scale".
We can look at our super weapons - a H-bomb releases 42-odd PettaJoules, which is (on the rough order of) an hour's energy budget for our K-0.7ish scale civilization.
Using "an hours energy budget" as a super weapon scale for a civilization, the 10^32 J/1 hour puts your galactic civilization at 10^28 Watts, above K2 a but not quite K3.  So this civilization considers a full dyson sphere to be an impressive feat of engineering - and they might have a few of them, or consider them to be boondoggles not worth building - but they haven't hit the point of harnessing the core black hole as an matter-energy annihilation engine yet (feeding it entire stellar masses as fuel).
Now that we understand the scale of the Galactic Empire - about K2.3 - we can look at their enemies.
Anything close to a full K scale down from the Galactic Empire is not worth being worried about.  So K1.5 is the absolute floor on how strong the target civilization has to be.
K1.5 does not have a significant fraction of its economy on any one planet.  Its energy budget is enough to cook 3 Earth-sized planets (like, just from waste heat, not from pollution).  Either they are spread over dozens or hundreds of Earth-scale planets, or they are mainly an interplanetary civilization.  Blowing up a single planet is closer to destroying a mid-sized city for a current-Earth superpower than wiping out their civilization.
Lifting 10 billion humans off an Earth-like planet, in 1 tonne per person escape capsules or ships, is 1/2 * 10 billion * 1 tonne * (11.2 km/s)^2 = 6 * 10^20 Joules.
If they have a mere 30 days notice, this is 3 * 10^14 Watts of energy - on the order of 0.00001% of their civilizations capabilities focused on this one task.  Or 0.5 seconds of power generation of their civilization.
How does this compare to evacuating a city to us?  Taking a city of 1 million people, putting them in cars that get 0.56 km/MJ, and driving them 100 km each requires 180 MJ * 1 million people - on the order of 10^14 Joules, or 10 seconds of power capabilities of our civilization.
So evacuating a mid-sized city is a bit harder for us (today) than it would be for a plausible target civilization to evacuate everyone off a planet.
Given any medium term warning, even if they can't stop the attack, there won't be casualties - admittedly, the debris from the exploded planet could cause havoc in the solar system!
Weaker or Stronger Target
If your target is much, it won't be able to do anything even if they see the weapon coming.  If the target is stronger, the damage of dismantling a single planet is going to be trivial.
Your weapon is serious overkill for a planet-bound civilization, and irrelevant to any civilization that is a threat to you.  It is akin to the USA designing weapons to destroy bow strings of enemies.
Sure, that means that enemies using bow strings are crippled, but any enemy that relies on bow strings to fight the USA is not a threat worth building a weapon to counter.
Weaker or Stronger Empire
It could be the case that this weapon is anomalously efficient or over scaled for your Empire.  Then its insane overkill makes some sense, as the Empire's more conventional weaponry won't be overwealmingly powerful for targets that are disabled by this super weapon.
If the Empire is stronger, than the weapon could be even more impressive.  Instead of just blowing up a planet, with a few orders of magnitude increase you could blow up the star with a kinetic impactor.
You'll still run into the problem that any target civilization worth shooting at will find the weapon not that impressive, because turning energy into "disassemble planet from a distance using kinetic impactor" isn't a very efficient use of weaponry.

Not to throw a spanner at the impressive calculations, but the question states the energy per slab to be 10²⁴J, a far cry of the 2,5×10³²J for the Earth. It is a planet annihilator probably in that it kills everything and everything on it. Not a gravity binding destroying one. You need substantially less for just killing everything. That being said, the size problem can still very much rear it's head, but with 'advanced future tech', I'm willing to overlook that detail.

@Trioxidane Sure - I probably took "once the gravitational binding energy is overcome by the deployed scales" too literally, as it applied to "planetoids".

My apologies! I had missed that one. They must have miniature planets, because you need a whole lot of those several ton slabs if you want to overcome an Earth sized planet's gravitational binding energy with 10²⁴J individual slabs.

Frame challenge
Stealthing it defeats the purpose of it being the ultimate sanction.
Not only must Justice be done, but must be seen to be done.
As such concealing it defeats it's purpose - not only to eradicate a threat but to serve as a warning to any other would be uppity planets to keep their toes in line, lest they get thwacked.

The victims of the weapon are not the ones who need to do the seeing. They'll be dead. The ones who need to see the wreckage that was once a planet, will see the ensuing debris cloud just fine.

To continue @KerrAvon2055 answer:

When the devourer travels at (close to) c, from its reference frame, the target travels towards it at (close to) c.
This means that the devourer observes the target like it was in the time light traveled to it.
Thus, there's no need for a complex species to try to flee, simply moving the target a few degree will not be observable by the devourer until it almost arrived (in Kerr's example, it's not observable at least 30 days before impact).
This means that the devourer must make the assumption that the celestial bodies follows some known and predictable path to program the scales before it releases them. It can't observe the celestial body at impact time, since what it'll see are the bodies at the d/c time before (with d the distance from the body to the devourer).
Changing its route direction at (close to) c would require a huge energy that the scale can't have (the volume of the devourer is mainly the engine, the scale can't have such a large engine each and can't expel enough matter to change their inertia much). The higher the moment of inertia, the higher the cost in matter to change it.

Thus, if a species is sufficiently advanced to require launching a devourer against, it's likely able to use all its resources to move a celestial body (either by thruster or collisions with another body). Hey, even us were able to move a small asteroid, so an advanced species should be able to move a moon or maybe a planet. A milliradian change would be enough for a scale to miss, and they only have one try at their speed.
Also, instead of moving the target, it's also possible to move any body in the trajectory to cause a small change in spacetime curvature, that would deviate the devourer or its scales. The moment the devourer account for it is too late for compensating due to light speed delay.
Also, although the destination can't know the devourer launch before it's launched, they could have spies in the Empire and those could have intercepted the devourer construction and target plan (it's unlikely a ship this size is built in a day from a single mind decision). Thus, the information could come up months before it's actually arriving.
